# Distributed caching on 64-bit Windows machines

Tags: windows, caching, 64-bit, memcached, distributed-caching

Are there any production-ready distributed caching mechanisms like memcached that can be used in a Windows 64-bit environment?  From what I've seen, memcached is run on linux machines in production environments, however I don't have control over the fact that we will be using 64-bit Windows machines.

Additional requirements include for any suggested solutions:

a robust .NET client API to consume this distributed cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcached runs on Windows, but we don't have the packaging solid yet.  A [good client](https://github.com/enyim/EnyimMemcached) has been available for a while.

Comment: Who is it that's working on Memcached on Windows?  Is there a road map for its future?  Is there any way in which I can contribute?  From my experience thus far, Memcached is the best solution for dealing with speeding up high traffic websites and offloading database hits and it's the way I'd like to go, but I, unfortunately, have no control over our infrastructure.

Comment: capttofu on github is doing the most with it right now.  The biggest part is making a build run consistently on Windows.  We do have preliminary releases over at http://labs.northscale.com/ but they haven't been brought into the master branches just yet.

Answer (score 3):

I know some of the guys in my office evaluated [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/) and the results were reasonably good.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [SharedCache](http://www.sharedcache.com/cms/)- free, open source, and 100% managed code. Works great on 64bit, and we use it for a large site (10's of thousands of users).

Answer (score 1):

The Velocity Framework (http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/06/30/a-lap-around-microsoft-quot-velocity-quot-cache-it-now.aspx) is Microsoft's solution to a memcached-like framework for .NET